# Como calcular a soma de divisores de forma rápida em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemática

Gostaria de saber como calcular, de forma rápida, a soma dos divisores de um número natural `n`, sendo 2 <= n < 10<sup>9</sup>. Para números pequenos, realizo esta operação tranquilamente com o seguinte código:

```
n = int(input())
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    m = int(input())
    soma = 0
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        if m % i == 0:
            soma += i
    print('{}'.format(soma))
```

Mas para números muito grandes o meu código não é eficiente.

Comment: Veja: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factors_of_an_integer#Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma pequena otimização é que você não precisa ir até `n`, [basta ir até a raiz quadrada de `n`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811176).

E para cada divisor que você encontrar, na verdade você encontrou - potencialmente - dois divisores. Por exemplo, se o número for 100 e você encontra o divisor 2, você também já encontrou o divisor 50 (resultado de 100 / 2). Então basta somar ambos, economizando uma iteração do *loop*. Só precisa tomar cuidado para o caso de quadrados perfeitos, para não contar duas vezes o mesmo divisor (por exemplo, se o número for 100, não podemos usar esta lógica com o divisor 10, senão ele será contado duas vezes).

Então ficaria assim:

```
import math

def soma_divisores(num):
    result = 1 + num
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(num)) + 1):
        d, r = divmod(num, i)
        if r == 0: # resto zero, é divisor
            result += i; 
            if i != d: # somar também o outro divisor encontrado
                result += d; 
    return result
```

Eu já começo somando 1 e o próprio número (pois ambos sempre serão divisores do número). Depois começo o *loop* no 2 e vou até a raiz quadrada do número, e aplico a lógica explicada acima. Para isso eu uso [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod), que já retorna o resultado da divisão e o resto desta mesma divisão.

---

Um pequeno teste usando o módulo [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) já mostra uma diferença significativa:

```
import math

def sum1(num):
    soma = 0
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            soma += i
    return soma

def sum2(num):
    result = 1 + num
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(num)) + 1):
        d, r = divmod(num, i)
        if r == 0:
            result += i; 
            if i != d:
                result += d; 
    return result

import timeit
n = 10 # executa a função 10 vezes
r = 3 # repete por 3 vezes cada execução de n vezes
num = 1000000 # 1 milhão
print(timeit.repeat('sum1(num)', repeat=r, number=n, globals=globals()))
print(timeit.repeat('sum2(num)', repeat=r, number=n, globals=globals()))
```

A execução varia de máquina para máquina, na minha o resultado foi:

```
[1.5477205, 1.6962128, 1.5432386]
[0.0020645000000003577, 0.002347499999999947, 0.0021449999999996194]
```

Ou seja, uma diferença bem grande (os tempos acima estão em segundos).
Testando com 10<sup>9</sup>, a diferença fica maior ainda (cerca de 3 minutos com o seu código, e 0.007 segundos - 7 milésimos de segundo - com o meu). Mas vale lembrar novamente que os tempos podem variar de acordo com o hardware, se há outras coisas executando na máquina ao mesmo tempo, etc.

[Rodando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/HauntingGranularRom#main.py), por exemplo, os tempos foram maiores que na minha máquina, mas a diferença entre os 2 algoritmos continua muito grande (5 minutos do seu código contra 11 centésimos de segundo do meu).