# Impressão de divisores em Python, com a soma dos mesmos na saída

Tags: python

Preciso criar um programa que apresente a soma de todos os divisores de um número, menos este número em si.

Ex: a soma dos divisores do número 66 é 1 + 2 + 3 + 6 + 11 + 22 + 33 = 78

No caso, preciso imprimir apenas o 78, como saída.

Meu programa, entretanto, está imprimindo todos os divisores. Como alterar isso, por gentileza?
Segue abaixo meu código:

```
divisor = 1

numero = int(input('Informe um número inteiro e positivo: '))
if numero < 0:
    numero = int(input('O número não pode ser negativo.\n Digite um número inteiro e positivo: '))
for divisor in range(divisor, numero):
    if numero % divisor == 0:
        print(divisor)
```

O meu código acima, retorna, por exemplo, se eu digitar 66, o seguinte:

```
1
2
3
6
11
22
33
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456301/112052

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como calcular a soma de divisores de forma rápida em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/456301/como-calcular-a-soma-de-divisores-de-forma-r%c3%a1pida-em-python)

Comment: Obrigado. Então, é que na verdade o hkotsubo tinha postado uma forma mais simples, contendo funções e recursos que eu já estudei, até o momento. Mas o post dele sumiu...rsrs

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

O maior motivo do erro é que não está fazendo a soma. Programar é interpretar o problema. Na sua descrição claramente tem um soma, no código não tem, então o problema é esse. Fazendo a soma dá certo.

Claro que você deve imprimir só a soma uma vez no final, não no laço porque o problema não pede para imprimir o acumulado em cada passo, na verdade, pelo que entendi, nem os divisores pede, mas pode ser que seja só porque um enunciado não esteja bom, se precisar basta colocar essa impressão no laço.

A validação tá esquisita porque se a pessoa digitar uma vez errado ele não deixa, mas deixa se o fizer na segunda, então o correto é ter um laço ali que só sai quando foi digitado um valor adequado.

Eu ainda não validei tudo, pode dar erro se a pessoa digitar algo que nem seja um número, p certo é tratar isso também, veja como fazer em [uma resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/428367/101) ou [O programa não está reconhecendo número inteiro como tal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/433050/101)

```
while True:
    numero = int(input('Digite um número inteiro e positivo: '))
    if numero >= 0:
        break
    print('O número não pode ser negativo.')
divisor = 1
soma = 0
for divisor in range(divisor, numero):
    if numero % divisor == 0:
        soma += divisor
print(soma)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AADvyE). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/aeiohzol-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Sum.py).